# .net 4.0 compatibility

Tags: .net

i write winforms application, using .net 4.0, linq, etc. will it work on machines with .net 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use .NET 4 features then no, it won't work on .NET 2.

If you *just* want to use LINQ to Objects and no other newer features, then you should look into [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/), which is a port of LINQ to Objects for .NET 2. You can then make Visual Studio target .NET 2 in your project properties, use the LINQBridge libraries, and your app should then work on a .NET 2 machine.

Note that you will still be able to use a lot of the features from C# 3 and 4, such as lambda expressions (but not expression trees), automatically implemented properties, anonymous types, optional parameters and named arguments etc. Obviously not everything will be available though - `dynamic` won't work on .NET 2 for example.

Comment: i need linq to sql to, what about it?

Comment: @eba: I don't know of a LINQ to SQL port to .NET 2, although it's just *possible* that you could take whatever Mono provides these days. If *at all possible* though, I would try to upgrade the target machines to .NET 3.5 or higher.

Answer (score 6):

No it will not. Applications compiled for Framework version 4.0 will require that framework to be present on the machine where the application will run.

Comment: is there a way to use linq with 2.0?

Comment: @eba, no, Linq was introduced in version 3.5 of the framework.